# How to get rid of adfly javascript code to be inserted automatically in my web pages

Tags: malware

in my website, adfly's javascript code is inserted automatically after every few hours in index.php and default.php web pages. Every time I remove these unwanted code from both pages manually and that code reappear again after few hours. I have no clue that how this is happened but due to this code, whenever I open above mentioned pages in browser, too many popup pages are opened automatically. How to stop this permanently because I am reading many articles on internet about this issue but still not able to find out any proper solution for last few days.

Thank you for reading this.